# Wpf common border style for all controls

Tags: wpf, app.xaml

I work in wpf
I use the following controls: 
Button
TextBox
TextBlock
Label
TreeView
ListView
ComboBox
Is there a way to set a default border (In App.xaml) for all of them ?
Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2):

I don't know other way than just setting for each type something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

or if you already have some default style for e.g. button

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

This will set default `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` for all buttons in your apps. You can also define `OnMouseOver` etc. behaviour here.

For TextBlock, you will have to define template too if you want to have some border, because `TextBlock` is primitive control, without `Border`. If you want border you can use `Label`, which is just `Textblock` with border outside.

Answer (score 0):

For everything, that use standart Border, you can create this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

If in any control Border created in other way, you will need to override it manually.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all
The solution for defining Style for the border works
The only exception is the TextBox because the TextBox does not have a border in it
The solution I found for the TextBox is to define the TextBox style as follows

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- Modify default template, to change triggers -->
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Ilan